# Finding a solution on Matlab for a quadratic programming-type problem with more restrictions

Tags: matlab, quadratic-programming

I have some existence results using one modified version of the Farkas Lemma for which I need to solve the following problem. This problem has its application on economics but I will refer here merely to its mathematical part to avoid confusions (and no, this is not homework).

I have a matrix $A \in \{-1,0,1 \}^{n\times m}$ (is this notation right? I mean it takes values from $\{-1,0,1\}$ and which is of size $n\times m$) with $m \ggg n$ (lots of columns, for example think of it as $50\times1000$) such that for each row only one of the following conditions hold:

1. all the numbers of the row are zeros and ones exclusively
2. all the numbers of the row are zeros and minus ones exclusively

So that a possible example for $A$ is:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
-1 & -1  & 0  & 0  & -1 \\ 
1 & 0  & 0  & 1  & 0 \\ 
-1 & 0  & 0  &0  & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

What I need to show is if there exists one $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x$ has only non-negative coordinates (ie. $x\geq 0$) such that $x\cdot A = 0$ with the standard dot product. 
 In particular, I want to distinguish two cases. If the only solution possible is $x=0$, or if there exists one solution for which at least one of the coordinates is different from zero. I am very, very interested in finding out if the second case is true. My aim is to explicitly show such $x$ if it exists.

I was using MATLAB via its `quadprog` function by stating a maximization problem that allows me to look $x$, and this method works if $n$, the number of rows in my matrix is small.  However, as $n$ grows this method becomes very deficient and it stops finding an $x\neq 0$. The problem I stated is $\max ||x||_2$ s.t. $x\cdot A = 0$ and $\bar{x}\geq x\geq 0$. This is the way I have been able to find such an x, but I am not forced to use this command so any other commands or possibilities are kindly appreciated.

With all of this context, can you think of a way of finding $x$?

Comment: Is $x$ a column vector? What do you mean by $xA$?  Why do you have $x \geq x$ as a constraint?

Comment: Yes it is a column vector. I use $\bar{x} \leq x$ precisely because if not the problem is not bounded (notice the bar on it) and without this restriction the maximizer would not exist as you can always multiply a non-zero feasible solution times a positive constant and get a bigger norm.

Comment: Oh sorry the bar over the $x$ didn't show up on my phone!  I'm not familiar with the notation $x \cdot A$ that you're using, because if $x$ is $n \times 1$ and $A$ is $n \times m$ then their dimensions aren't compatible to form the matrix product $xA$.  You mention the standard dot product, but what do you mean by the dot product of a column vector with a matrix?  Do you mean $A^T x$?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, yes, I meant $A'\cdot x$ with $x$ being a row vector or $x \cdot A$ with $x$ being a column vector.